# Calendar with 24h

Tags: calendar

I have a Mac set in English (US) with an US keyboard. I'm european so I want to have 24h in my calendar and not AM and PM. How it is possible to enable that? I enable that for the hour of the computer, but this didn't changed the calendar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go into "System Preferences=>Language & Text" where you select the **Region** tab.

Under **Times** you click on the "Customize" button, and remove the PM time element in the "Short:" box above. Also be sure to choose the right 24h time format (1-24 or 01-24 - or one of the other) in the "Short:" box

Answer (score 1):

Under System settings -> Language & Text select the pane Region. You can set any format you want. Usually it suffices to change the region, e.g. from United States (12 h times with AM/PM) to United Kingdom (24h times). This influences all applications, also the calendar. It takes effect immediately and you can see the effect in the open calendar at once, i.e. without restarting it.

Comment: I made it when I changed the hour of the computer, customizing the section "Time". This didn't changed the Calendar... If i choose my region, it works but it changes also language (dates are in my language and not in english)... Do you know how to fix that?